# TailwindCSS breakpoints not triggering

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css

So I have a h1 that I want to change size after hitting the medium breakpoint (md).

```
<h1
          className="text-7xl md:text-8xl text-white "
          style={{ fontFamily: "Yellowtail" }}
>
```

For some reason, it only applies the 7xl and does not change when I rezize my window. I've tried it with other elements as well, and it seems like the breakpoints are never triggered.

I don't know if it's worth noting that I'm using https://material-tailwind.com/ as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you made with default install tailwind, then it will support from `text-sm` to `text-9xl`.
So please show your `tailwind.config.js` and main css file like(`index.js` or `App.js`) in your code to get more detailed advice.

Also check your `text-color`, now you defined as `white`, so if your background color is white, then you can't nothing, so test with delete text-white or change with other colors. good luck! :)

```
<h1 className="text-7xl md:text-8xl" style={{ fontFamily: "Yellowtail" }}>HH</h1>
```